# Why isn't my JavaScript saving data locally?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try to have my game save, but it doesn't. When it does save, the program lags and resets. I want the game to save the player's $$$, XP, swag, and multiplier bonus. I have called my advisors, they cannot help the situation. I have been fidling with local data save and nothing will seem to work.
[image]
sad.png
[image]
cloud1.gif

```js
    //variables and stuff
    var button = document.getElementById("mir");
    var walletDisp = document.getElementById("walletDisp");
    var xpDisp = document.getElementById("xplabel");
    var test = document.getElementById("test");
    var upgradeCashButton = document.getElementById("updaCash");
    var upgradeCloudButton = document.getElementById("updaCloud");
    var cloudLevelMax = 298123019;
    var bonus = 100000;
    var bonusCount = 2139871;
    var wallet = 234018933098452034985;
    var cashPerClick = 10000;
    var xp = 132412341;
    var cloudLevel = 320948;
    var sad = true;
    
    var aNiceTimer=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1000);
    
    //the "get her going" script
    button.addEventListener("click", makeItRain, false);
    upgradeCashButton.addEventListener("click",upgradeCash, false);
    upgradeCloudButton.addEventListener("click",upgradeCloud, false);
    xpDisp.addEventListener("click",credits, false);
    window.onload = doInit();
    chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(details){
                                           if(xp=="undefined"){
                                            saveUs();
                                           }
                                           save();
                                           });
    
    function myTimer() {
     if(sad===false){if(clicked===false){
      document.body.style.backgroundImage="url('res/sad.jpg')";
      sad = true;
            bonus =1;
            bonusCount = 0;
            updateOutput();
     }}
        if(clicked){
            bonusCount = bonusCount +.7;
        }
        if(bonusCount>bonus){
            bonus = bonus+1;
            bonusCount = 0;
            updateOutput();
        }
     clicked = false;
    
    }
    
    function makeItRain(){
        if(isNaN(wallet)){
            saveUs();
        }
     wallet = wallet+cashPerClick*bonus;
     if(sad===true){updateBackground();}
     sad = false;
     clicked = true;
        xp = xp+bonus;
     updateOutput();
    }
    
    function updateOutput(){
        xpDisp.innerHTML = "Level "+ Math.round(Math.log(xp) / Math.log(10));
     walletDisp.innerHTML = dispNumb(wallet)+"$";
     upgradeCashButton.innerHTML = "Up to " +(dispNumb(getCashUpgrade())) +
        " for "+ dispNumb(costOfCashUpgrade())+ "$";
        upgradeCloudButton.innerHTML = "Add Swag? "+dispNumb(costOfCloudUpgrade())+"$";
        if(clicked===true){
            button.innerHTML = "Bonus: x "+ bonus;
        }else{
            button.innerHTML = "Rain those $$$";
        }
        if(wallet>=costOfCashUpgrade()){
            upgradeCashButton.style.background='#6fae3c';
            upgradeCashButton.style.border='3px solid #5f9e2c';
        }else{
            upgradeCashButton.style.background='#FA5858';
            upgradeCashButton.style.border='3px solid #FE2E2E';
        }
        if(wallet>=costOfCloudUpgrade()){
            upgradeCloudButton.style.background='#6fae3c';
            upgradeCloudButton.style.border='3px solid #5f9e2c';
        }else{
            upgradeCloudButton.style.background='#FA5858';
            upgradeCloudButton.style.border='3px solid #FE2E2E';
        }
        save();
    }
    function upgradeCash(){
     if(wallet<costOfCashUpgrade()){
      return;
     }
     wallet = wallet - costOfCashUpgrade();
     cashPerClick = getCashUpgrade();
        xp = xp+costOfCashUpgrade();
        updateOutput();
    }
    function upgradeCloud(){
        if(wallet<costOfCloudUpgrade()){
      return;
     }
        if(cloudLevel==cloudLevelMax){
            window.location='STOP.html';
            return;
        }
     wallet = wallet - costOfCloudUpgrade();
     cloudLevel = cloudLevel+1;
        xp = xp+costOfCloudUpgrade();
        updateBackground();
        sad = false;
        updateOutput();
    }
    function getCashUpgrade(){
        numb = cashPerClick;
        if(numb<10){
            return numb+1;
        }
        var first = String(numb).charAt(0);
        if(first=="1"){
            first = "2";
        }else if(first=="2"){
            first = "5";
        }else if(first=="5"){
            first = "10";
        }
        var rest = String(numb).substring(1,String(numb).length);
        return parseInt( first+""+rest);
    }
    function dispNumb(number){
        var long = String(number).length;
        var temp = 0;
        var ending = "hi";
        if(long<4){
            return number;
        }
        if(long<7){
            temp = Math.round(number/10)/100;
            ending = "K";
        }else if(long<10){
            temp = Math.round(number/10000)/100;
            ending = "M";
        }else if(long<13){
            temp = Math.round(number/10000000)/100;
            ending = "B";
        }else if(long<16){
            temp = Math.round(number/10000000000)/100;
            ending = "T";
        }
        temp = parseFloat(temp).toFixed(2);
        return temp + " " +ending;
    }
    function costOfCashUpgrade(){
     return Math.round(4*Math.round(10*cashPerClick*Math.log(cashPerClick)*Math.log(cashPerClick)))+1;
    }
    function updateBackground(){
        document.body.style.backgroundImage="url('res/cloud"+cloudLevel+".gif')";
    }
    function costOfCloudUpgrade(){
        return Math.round(10*Math.pow(4+cloudLevel,cloudLevel+3));
    }
    function save(){
     chrome.storage.local.set({"wallet": wallet});
     chrome.storage.local.set({"cashPerClick": cashPerClick});
        chrome.storage.local.set({"xp": xp});
        chrome.storage.local.set({"cloudLevel": cloudLevel});
    }
    function load(){
        chrome.storage.local.get("wallet", function(item){
                                 wallet = item["wallet"];
                                 });
        chrome.storage.local.get("cashPerClick", function(item){
                                 cashPerClick = item["cashPerClick"];
                                 });
        chrome.storage.local.get("xp", function(item){
                                 xp = item["xp"];
                                 });
        chrome.storage.local.get("cloudLevel", function(item){
                                 cloudLevel = item["cloudLevel"];
                                 });
    }
    function becomeOneWithWorld(){
        var walB = 0;
        var cpcB = 0;
        var xpB = 0;
        var clB = 0;
        chrome.storage.sync.get("wallet", function(item){
                                walB = item["wallet"];
                                });
        chrome.storage.sync.get("cashPerClick", function(item){
                                cpcB = item["cashPerClick"];
                                });
        chrome.storage.sync.get("cloudLevel", function(item){
                                clB = item["cloudLevel"];
                                });
        chrome.storage.sync.get("xp", function(item){
                                xpB = item["xp"];
                                });
        setTimeout(function () {
            if(xp>xpB){
                chrome.storage.sync.set({"wallet": wallet});
                chrome.storage.sync.set({"cashPerClick": cashPerClick});
                chrome.storage.sync.set({"xp": xp});
                chrome.storage.sync.set({"cloudLevel": cloudLevel});
            }else{
                chrome.storage.local.set({"wallet": walB});
                chrome.storage.local.set({"cashPerClick": cpcB});
                chrome.storage.local.set({"xp": xpB});
                chrome.storage.local.set({"cloudLevel": clB});
            }
            load();
        }, 100);
    }
    
    function saveUs(){
        wallet = 0;
        cashPerClick = 1;
        xp = 1;
        cloudLevel = 1;
    }
    
    function credits(){
        window.location='credit.html';
    }
    function doInit(){
        load();
        becomeOneWithWorld();
    }
```

Comment: Narrow the issue down - we're not going to go through a giant block of code like this. First thing to try - a tiny, simple script that just saves and then retrieves data in/from local storage. See if *that* works first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the wrong APIs. The `chrome.storage` and `chrome.runtime` APIs are for Chrome extensions, not web sites.

To store data using Javascript in a web page, use [the LocalStorage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Comment: No, you don't want to create an extension for a web game. You just need to use the correct form of storage like suggested.